# Is it bad using $_SESSION['id'] in queries?

Tags: php, mysql

When person logins, he gets `$_SESSION['id']` and it becomes his id taken from mysql table. Then I do mysql queries like `SELECT * FROM members WHERE member_id = {$_SESSION['id']}`.

So, is it safe? Can $_SESSION['id'] disappear or could hacker edit it somehow?

Thank you.

Comment: If there's a code path that could lead to this query being executed without going through the code that sets the session variable, then "yes", the variable could "disappear" by simply forcing a new session then going down that code path.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would argue that it is *always* bad to create a query by simply inserting or concatenating variables. Instead, you should use a [Prepared Statement](http://www.ultramegatech.com/blog/2009/07/using-mysql-prepared-statements-in-php/) that will guarantee protection against SQL Injection type attacks. IMHO, they also make code look better.

Answer (score 2):

In theory, there is no way that clients can affect $_SESSION array, beacuse session data is stored on the server. But in practice, never trust this, because hacker can use another security hole and substitude $_SESSION['id'] with something bad.

Do this, before putting id into your query:

```
$_SESSION['id'] = intval($_SESSION['id']);
```

Comment: What kind of security hole? To change the session remotely, you'd need direct access to the session storage medium, or find some intermediate hole in the OP's code. As long there isn't something like `$_SESSION['id'] = $_GET['hidden_s33krit_id_overrride']`, I can't see how a session variable can get changed by a remote malicious user.

Comment: Session id's are NOT integers, so you'd be returning 0 for every user. http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-id.php

Comment: @Marc so, on a lame hosting it's just enough to buy yourself an account to be able edit other's sessions in /tmp/

Comment: @Col: If you're on shared hosting, there is no security to begin with. Why bother hacking up the session when you could just modify the script in the first place, or extract DB credentials and go even deeper?

Comment: @Marc if you're on lame shared hosting and can manipulate session files, there is still a huge difference. If you do an `intval` check, the attacker can impersonate some other user (which is bad enough), but they can't do SQL injection. Which is why I say this is a check worthy of doing, it doesn't cost anybody anything.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($con, "SELECT Name FROM members WHERE member_id = ? LIMIT 1");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $_SESSION['id']);
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $name);
mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt);
mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);

echo 'name is '.$name;
?>
```

Comment: session can not be changed but some how hacked, if you got Firefox and COOKIE editor you can see the PHPSESID 's content, this is the file name where the session data is stored, if user alters it with a successful then he hacks other's session !

Comment: you can try with mysqli_real_escape_string if you love mysqli_query :P

Comment: the hacker would have go guess a valid session id, not an easy task... Unless he can inject some javascript (this is called XSS) to have some poor soul's cookies send to said hacker.

Answer (score 0):

You're right to be suspect since header vars are in the control of users.

You generate a valid id, but I could tamper with it by, for example, setting my $_SESSION['id'] to `1234 OR 1==1` and that (theoretically) would return all user records unless you sanitize that variable.

It's OK to take user data, but always validate it. Set it to a temporary variable, then run something like `preg_replace("[^A-Za-z0-9]", "", $_SESSION['id'])` to remove any non-alphanumeric characters. That alone is not enough, but it's a step toward safer user input and away from so-called "SQL injection."

Comment: `$_SESSION['id']` is not a header var?

Answer (score 0):

As already suggested, you should never assume type safety. Not because someone can hack you, also because YOU can make a mistake or the person who configured your server. Since PHP's sessions can be stored in the file system (default), they can be stored within Memcache or you can write your own session storage handler (storing sessions in db).
Say a mistake occurred - you saved sessions to the database, you tampered with the db and you changed a value by mistake to something else, and instead of integers (or floating point types), you're receiving strings with commas and what not - which do not fit your query you posted above - and voila, you're getting errors. No one likes to get errors and read error descriptions - especially not your users.

So, to answer your question - it is bad to TRUST anyone. Never trust foreign input, there's always more than one point of failure - clean your input for safety, be it _POST, _GET, _SESSION or anything else.

Answer (score -1):

It is **always** bad to **think**. To think if some variable is safe or not.
You are a programmer. Let you program think of such trifle things and turn to something more interesting.

Comment: A programmer should always be aware what values a variable can and can not contain. How else can you know what kind of checks the program should perform on it?

Comment: The downvote isn't mine, but I don't understand what you mean by this. Would you not agree that it's at least useful to do an `intval` on the variable before putting it into a query?

Comment: Yes I do. But I don't agree with the broad statement presented above. Not thinking leads to assumption and that is exactly what causes security errors. Do the intval and be aware why you are doing it. Not just mindlessly run everything through intval and then assume all is safe and well in the world.

Answer (score -1):

What is and is not in `$_SESSION` is basically under your control. Apart from using some advanced stuff like hacking the server and editing your temporary PHP storage files, the browser has no control over this.

Almost every authentication relies on the setting of some variable in the SESSION array to keep track of the current user. This can be regarded as safe. As long as you avoid specifically handing control over to the browser with statements such as:

```
$_SESSION['id'] = $_POST['id']
```

or the like.

Nevertheless, the others answers about never constructing database queries by string concatenation are valid. It is good practice to *always* run things through `mysql_real_escape_string()`, so being a good programmer, you use a wrapper function/class that automates that for you, so you never ever get it wrong.